# Script JS Google docs

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma planilha no Google docs igual as imagens abaixo. Na figura 1 que é planilha tenho a URL do site que vai ser monitorada e enviada para o e-mail que for inserida, ao lado tenho na Tabela C ele mostra se o site esta respondendo ou não e na tabela D ele mostra o horário que houve o erro de comunicação. Tudo isso que eu descrevi está funcionando, o *script* que foi montado está em `Ferramentas -> Editor de Script`, esse *script* faz funcionar a tabela e envia os relatórios para meu e-mail.

O ponto em que preciso de ajuda: na tabela baixo eu preciso monitorar o IP a porta e nome do `arquivo.ogg` como mostra na primeira imagem, porém ele sempre mostra que a URL não existe acredito que seja por causa da linhas que deixei em negrito que apenas fazem ping e não checam se o arquivo existe ou não:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o Codigo do script de checagem:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
startRow = 2,  // skips header line
lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() -1, // get last line with data
dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow, 3), // first value is the row, second is the column in number
data = dataRange.getValues(); // get data of every cell within the range


function checkAllSites() {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i],
    siteUrl = row[0],
    notificationEmail = row[1],
    currentRow = (startRow+i),
    wasItAvailable = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 3), //getRange is 1-based instead of 0-based 
    lastCheckDate = sheet.getRange(currentRow, 4),
    timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/Sao_Paulo", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

**if(!pingSite(siteUrl)) { // Let's try to open the site and check if we get a success** response
  var subject = "Your site is unavailable :(",
        message = "We tried to check your site " + siteUrl + " at " + timestamp + " but it was unavailable!";
    MailApp.sendEmail(notificationEmail, subject, message);      
    wasItAvailable.setValue('no');      
  } else {
    wasItAvailable.setValue('yes');
  }    
 lastCheckDate.setValue(timestamp);
 }
};

function pingSite(url) {
  var status;

try{
  **status = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getResponseCode();**
  if(status>=200 && status<=206){
    return true;
  } else{
  return false;
 }
} catch(error){ // the typical error that might occur here is DNS related. No matter what happens instead of HTTP 2xx code, we'll consider an error
return false;
}
};
```

Comment: Você recebe algum erro no console?

Comment: Resolveu seu problema?